# Execute program conditionally

Tags: cmake

I am opening a file from CMake which will be open in a installed tool in my PC from the following command but the tool is not available in the server which throwing an error during the build.kindly help me to skip that part in server.

```
COMMAND ${Src_File_gen} -f "${CMAKE_SRC_DIR}/Source.xyz" -g -m ${_VARIANT}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_program.html) before calling the tool. Then wrap the calling CMake command in an `if` condition only executing when the program was found:

```
find_program(SRC_FILE_GEN <src_file_gen_exe>)

if(${SRC_FILE_GEN})
  COMMAND ${SRC_FILE_GEN} -f "${CMAKE_SRC_DIR}/Source.xyz" -g -m ${_VARIANT}
endif()
```